# Remove regex from filenames, while piping them

Tags: bash, regular-expression, rename

I'm converting a bash of files from `iso-latin-1` (aka, `iso-8859-1`) to `utf-8`. In this process, I have the opportunity to rename the files. And, I would like to seize this opportunity to change the error-prone written name-format of the files.

The files have names as such:

```bsh
tree Dados/Jan/
```

```bsh
Dados/Jan/
├── 201301_Licitacoes
│   ├── 201301_EmpenhosRelacionados.csv
│   ├── 201301_ItemLicitaЗ╞o.csv
│   ├── 201301_LicitaЗ╞o.csv
│   └── 201301_ParticipantesLicitaЗ╞o.csv
├── 201401_Licitacoes
│   ├── 201401_EmpenhosRelacionados.csv
│   ├── 201401_ItemLicitaЗ╞o.csv
│   ├── 201401_LicitaЗ╞o.csv
│   └── 201401_ParticipantesLicitaЗ╞o.csv
├── 201501_Licitacoes
│   ├── 201501_EmpenhosRelacionados.csv
│   ├── 201501_ItemLicitaЗ╞o.csv
│   ├── 201501_LicitaЗ╞o.csv
│   └── 201501_ParticipantesLicitaЗ╞o.csv
├── 201601_Licitacoes
│   ├── 201601_EmpenhosRelacionados.csv
│   ├── 201601_ItemLicitaЗ╞o.csv
│   ├── 201601_LicitaЗ╞o.csv
│   └── 201601_ParticipantesLicitaЗ╞o.csv

(...)
```

I'm executing the following:

```bsh
find Dados/Jan/ -maxdepth 2 -name '*.csv' -exec sh -c 'conv {}' \;
```

in which, `conv` is the following script:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62918711/convert-multiple-csv-files-to-utf-8-encoding-using-a-script-windows-command-prom

for file in $@; do
    iconv -f ISO-8859-1 UTF-8 <"$file" >"$file".tmp &&
    mv "$file.tmp" "$file"
done
```

In this process, I would like to remove the "**З╞o**" text from the file names, which came as it is, when I unziped the files (probably someone used "**~**" on the names of the files etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use shell "parameter expansion" when `mv`ing the file to its final destination. Like

```
mv "$file.tmp" "${file//З╞o}"
```

Is it always the same character sequence?

Comment: Yes! It is. This will do. Thank you. But, the order of the `/` are switched. I would like to accept both of your awnsers, because both are correct.

Answer (score 4):

Use `bash`'s "pattern substitution" (read `man bash`) and do something like:

```
echo mv "$file.tmp" "${file/3|-o//}"
```

Remove the `echo` if you like the result. Never test with the actual `mv` command, data loss could result.

Comment: This is correct, and worked out. I would like to accept both your awnser and RudiC's, but I can't. So, I will accept his awnser, because his were first. Thank you for you time and explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Most probably `LicitaЗ╞o` is meant to be `Licitação`, which is portuguese for Licitation.

You could do a hard conversion by using `${var//icitaЗ╞o/icitação}` like:

```bsh
for file in "$@"; do
    filedest="${file//icitaЗ╞o/icitação}"
    iconv -f ISO-8859-1 UTF-8 <"$file" >"$file".tmp &&
    mv "$file.tmp" "$filedest"
    [[ $file != $filedest ]] && rm "$file"
done
```

Comment: Oh, no, I'm trying to avoid giving utf-8 names to files. It's what cause this issue, on the first place. But thanks; although, I understood that already, because I'm Brazilian :)

Answer (score 3):

Write the converted file to its required target filename and then remove the original

```
for file in "$@"
do
    iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 <"$file" >"${file/З╞o/}" &&
        rm -f -- "$file"
done
```

Notice also that `"$@"` is now double-quoted. This is required so that it doesn't act (wrongly) like `$*`.

Finally, the `find` can be simplified since this script can accept multiple parameters:

```
find Dados/Jan/ -maxdepth 2 -name '*.csv' -exec conv {} +
```

Comment: Thank you, I added that in my script